# Read a file character by character in reverse -- from a given position backwards

Tags: java

I know how to read single character, one at a time, **forward**:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String... args) {
        try (FileReader filereader = new FileReader("tempfile.txt")) {
            try (BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(filereader )) {
                 int c = reader.read();
                 if (c > 32) {
                   // do something here
                 }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                 e.printStackTrace();
            }
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
           e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
           e.printStackTrace();
        }
   }
}
```

But how do I do the same **backwards, from a given position** in the file?

Comment: [This might get you started](https://netjs.blogspot.com/2016/02/how-to-read-file-from-last-line-in-java.html).

Comment: @Eritrean Indeed this looks in the right direction. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [`RandomAccessFile`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/RandomAccessFile.html) to jump to a location where you want to read the next data. Use the [`seek()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/RandomAccessFile.html#seek-long-) method to go backwards from a given position.

Comment: Isn't this extremely inefficient? Is there a more efficient way of reading a file (character-by-character) backwards?

Comment: @JaySouper You don't need to read the bytes one-by-one, you can do bigger steps and read these chunks forward. But that depends on the actual use case you have and the requirements.

Comment: I have a 10GB text input file that won't fit into a String or a StringBuilder...  :)